# Sliding mobile nav overflow

Tags: css, overflow, user-experience

I'm working on a mobile navigation option for my site and want it to slide from the right.

Here's a mockup:

https://codepen.io/rctneil/pen/OqzBjX

The issue I have is that by default the page scrolls over to the right when the nav is hidden.

I've tried adding `overflow: hidden` to `.mega-wrapper` which stops this scroll, but also hides the navigation when the toggle button is clicked.

Any ideas?

Kind regards,
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that adding overflow: hidden was a good step. But after that you need to positioned absolute the `mega-wrapper__mobile-nav` and translateX the `mega-wrapper__wrapper` and `mega-wrapper__mobile-nav`

I made a [demo](https://codepen.io/MichalOrsag/pen/QoaJEx?editors=1100)

Comment: Well from your demo it seems like it works but i cant get my head around what it is doing.  So I have the .mega-wrapper__wrapper and .mega-wrapper_,mobile-nav as flex items side by side.  How does positioning the nav absolutely work?   Not arguing here, just like to wrap my brain around it! :-)

Comment: I refactored that demo and removed flexbox. So as you can see you need just wrapper with position: relative (you need it for nav with position: absolute) then set `mega-wrapper__wrapper` to full size width and then remove the nav [from the flow with position: absolute](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) set the new position for the nav and after that you can just change translateX